# Installing pandas in django

Tags: django, python-2.7, pandas

I have installed numpy and pandas in ubuntu 12.04. Also, I have added django_pandas in my INSTALLED_APPS but then also I am getting 
ImportError: No module named django_pandas
how should i proceed now

Comment: is django pandas on your python path? are you using virtualenv?

Comment: no i am not using virtualenv. i have directly installed numpy and pandas

Comment: sorry for the question. i havent correctly executed the command
pip install https://github.com/chrisdev/django-pandas/tarball/master.
after going for the above command it worked fine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

sorry for the question. i havent correctly executed the command
pip install https://github.com/chrisdev/django-pandas/tarball/master.
after going for the above command it worked fine

Answer (score 3):

There are no extra steps you need to take to install "Pandas in Django", just install Django and Pandas using pip:

```
pip install django
pip install pandas
```

Comment: you also need to execute https://github.com/chrisdev/django-pandas/tarball/master to make pandas run with django